# C ++ email not being sent

Tags: c++, curl

I can't send a letter using the curl library. Writes an error unsupported protocol. I use the standard code from the official site: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html
I tried different options, none came up:

```
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.gmail.com:465");
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://smtp.gmail.com");
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp.gmail.com");
curl_easy_setopt (curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://gmail.com");
```

Error message: curl_easy_perform() failed: Unsupported protocol

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] not just how you set up the options.

Comment: I left a link, I can't add a lot of code to the question

Comment: @t.niese actually in this specific instance, a minimal reproducible example wouldn't help much, the problem is the lib he is linking against. (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use smtp, you need to use a libcurl compiled with `--enable-smtp`, eg

```
./configure --with-ssl --enable-smtp
make -j $(nproc)
```

the libcurl you are linking against was not compiled with smtp support. if you're wondering how to compile libcurl yourself, maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/56394968/1067003