# getting error while executing curl command

Tags: curl, openssl, wget

I am trying to make an api call to https server via curl and getting
`curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version` error. The site/server to which I am trying to connect has self signed certificates.

This is the curl command that I am using [image]

This is the curl version [image]

Output of wget

[image]

I have tried adding `-k` or `--insecure` option to  in the curl command but getting same error.

Am I missing something or is there any other way to make this happen?

More verbosely:
[image]

Comment: is that perhaps an ancient SSL3 server? use -v and try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56377171/how-to-compile-curl-with-legacy-ssl-support-on-ubuntu/56394968#56394968

Answer (score 0):

As you are suspecting certificate shenanigans I  suggest giving try `--no-check-certificate` option of GNU Wget that is please try following command

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://10.0.9.94
```

and write what was effect.

Comment: thanks for the answer. After applying mentioned option, I am getting the same error as previously.